# Restoring fragment in FragmentStatePagerAdapter restores wrongly

Tags: android, fragment

I have a quiz app that displays multiple choice questions (`TextView` with 5 `RadioButtons` as choices below) as fragments in a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` within a `ViewPager`.

The error I'm getting is only when the fragment restores. Flicking forward, it loads each question and all 5 choices perfectly. However when it is restoring it is loaded completely wrong where all 5 `RadioButtons` display the same text, specifically that of the last `RadioButton`. I can't work out why this error would occur however I'm thinking it might be something to do with calling through to the super class but this is just a hunch.

Here's the code:

`OnCreateView` sets the text correctly as determined by logcat:

```
for (String s : aArray) {
// Runs through a string array of the 5 answers
        LinearLayout l = lArray.get(pos);

            RadioButton r = (RadioButton) l.findViewById(R.id.radio);
            Log.d(s, correctanswer);
//Log tag shows that the choices during initial creation or **restore** are the different 5 answers
            r.setText(s);
        }
    return rootView;
```

Then this is my `OnViewStateRestored`:

```
public void onViewStateRestored(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
    for (LinearLayout l : lArray) {
        RadioButton r = (RadioButton) l.findViewById(R.id.radio);
        Log.e(r.getText().toString(), correctanswer);
//Suddenly the displayed text is the same for all 5 buttons
        if (r.isChecked())
            r.performClick();
//android automatically saves check status. for full restore I click all the buttons
    }
}
```

If you require more code from OnCreateView or anything else let me know. I can't seem to work out what's causing this problem and thank you very much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of your radio buttons should have a different id, rather than them all having the same id. That's how radio buttons and other views save state, through the id. Well, to be more accurate, they save their state in a SparseArray mapped by their id. Hence why they all have the information of the 5th one on restore.

Comment: That's right -- android uses those ids when it automatically saves and restores the state of the views, and because all of your radio buttons have the same id, that results in the described behaviour.

Comment: Sounds logical enough - testing :D